# How to set a value to DropDownList items in ASP.Net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code for a `DropDownList` in ASP.Net :

```html
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Width="150px" 
                AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Tronc">Tronc Commun</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Sc_Maths">Bac 1 Sc Maths</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Sc_Ex">Bac 1 Sc Ex</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Eco_Ges">Bac 1 Economie et de Gestion</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="MathsA">Bac 2 Sc Maths A</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="P_C">Bac 2 Sc P.C.</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="S_V_T">Bac 2 Sc S.V.T.</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

what i want is the C# code to fill this `DropDownList` with these same items with the values, the code i was able to do is this but it only fill it with the items but not the values

```C#
str = "(...)";
con = new SqlConnection(str);
req = "select Classe, value from contact";
da = new SqlDataAdapter(req, con);
dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) 
    DropDownList3.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
```

Comment: `DropDownList3.Items.Add` is this a typo? because from your code the ID is `DropDownList2`

Comment: You have only one item in the select query. Is there any other column for Text and Value fields?

Comment: @Izzy well i puted 2 `DropDownLists` one filled with ASP.Net code (`DropDownList2`) and the other is the one i want to fill with same items (with their same values) using C#.

Comment: @SelvaTS i puted only 1 Column in that table just to show the code i usualy do, i'll edit it now so no one will misunderstand it

Comment: @TonnerMààn I have posted my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you load values from the DB. For that just adjust your select statement to include necessary field:

```
req = "select Classe, value from contact";
```

And then insert list items instead of just plain string into the drop down control:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ListItem item = new ListItem(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString(), dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
    DropDownList3.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: i puted only 1 Column in that table just to show the code i usualy do, i already edited it as a response to another comment lol, i'll try your code and give you feed back now : )

Comment: @TonnerMààn, your edit got lost because of the other one. I've recovered it now. As it turns out I have guessed the value field almost right, changed answer to lowercase `value` to stick to your use case

Comment: it is a lowercase `value` lol i wrote it manually here so i made that mistake thank you for correcting it, also this code worked, so thank you for your help ^_^

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DataTextField`, `DataValueField` properties to bind the data.

```
            str = "(...)";
            con = new SqlConnection(str);
            req = "select Classe, value from contact";
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(req, con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            DropDownList2.DataSource = dt;
            DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Classe";
            DropDownList2.DataValueField = "value";
            DropDownList2.DataBind();
```

Comment: Testing this code right now and giving feedback in a min : )

Comment: Worked ! Thank you very much, unfortunatly i can't accept more than 1 answer so i kept the accepted at the other Andrei's as he was first :P